# Get latitude, longitude from restfb

Tags: restfb

I used to use fql to get latitude and longitude from Place.

How do I do it nowadays?  I've got the user's location, but only id and name are filled in.  Everything else is null.  Code:

```
FacebookClient fc = new DefaultFacebookClient(token, Version.VERSION_2_9);
User user = fc.fetchObject("me", User.class, Parameter.with("location"));
Location loc = fc.fetchObject(user.getLocation().getId(), Location.class);
```

Also tried:

```
Place pl = fc.fetchObject(user.getLocation().getId(), Place.class);
```

Same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the RestFB [bugtracker](https://github.com/restfb/restfb/issues/772):

```
FacebookClient fc = new DefaultFacebookClient(token, Version.VERSION_2_9);
User user = fc.fetchObject("me", User.class, Parameter.with("fields","location"));
Page pageOfUserLocation = fc.fetchObject(user.getLocation().getId(), 
Page.class, Parameter.with("fields","location");
if (pageOfUserLocation.getLocation() != null) {
  System.out.println("longitude: ", pageOfUserLocation.getLocation().getLongitude());
  System.out.println("latitude: ", pageOfUserLocation.getLocation().getLatitude());
}
```

Comment: Thank you!

One more thing, in case others are as behind in updating as I was: Page.getLocation().getName() is null.  But user.getLocation().getName() has the location string.